# Laravel pagination meta data

Tags: laravel-5, vue.js

How do I get the following info with my json response:

```
current_page: 1,
from:1
```

I use pagination like this:

```
$rides = $user->rides()
            ->with('user', 'location', 'type')
            ->paginate(1);
```

It should be set by default. (https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/pagination)

(I am using vue.js)

Thankyou

Comment: You have access to helpers method `$rides->currentPage()` !

Comment: Here's the list of all available methods https://laravel.com/api/5.2/Illuminate/Contracts/Pagination/LengthAwarePaginator.html

Comment: Thankyou that works